# Why does my D-Link Router keeps dropping my Outlook and Lync connection?

Tags: router, wireless-router

my configuration is as follows: Internet connection coming from the office (don't know details) => [D-Link DIR-632](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=DIR-632) => Desktop Computer (Win 7), printer, Vonage.

I have Microsoft Lync and Outlook 2010. Both keep dropping on and off. For Lync it disconnects and then reconnects every 5 minutes or so. Outlook sends and receives fine at first and then eventually it stops receiving mail. I use it with an Exchange Server (Office 365), Hotmail (Outlook Connector), and IMAP (gmail). If I then restart Outlook mail starts coming in and eventually stops again.

The router is not restarting because I can still browse the web and Windows doesn't notify me of a failed network connection.

If I remove the router out of the equation (plugin in the internet directly to the desktop), this behavior doesn't occur.

My question is, is this a bad router or do I need to configure something?

Comment: I don't know that particular router, but I've had pretty horrible luck with D-Link routers in the past.

Comment: Chances are this is a firewall issue or a problem with NAT traversal. Look for active firewalling settings like ALG, SPI or intrusion detection. Make sure that all ports that these applications use are open/forwarded correctly.

Comment: In reference to my last comment: http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/DIR-632/Manuals/dir632_manual_100.pdf - page 33 for port forwarding, 34 for application rules (may work better than port forwarding), page 42 for firewall settings (antispoof may be bad, DMZ may help).

Comment: @MaQleod Can you be more specific on what you mean by `make sure these ports are...open/forwarded correctly`? What setting for open/forward consitutes correctly for this issue?

Comment: @SAFX, some applications or devices use multiple ports, it may be that only part of the range was forwarded so that certain signals in order to keep a session alive were not making it through and therefore cutting off the session. I have see this happen frequently with SIP devices.

Comment: @MaQleod In my Netgear router, I changed NAT Filtering to Open instead of Secured. That fixed the timeout issue with Lync client, but I don't like this solution since it leaves me vulnerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on MaQleod comments above, I logged in to the Router's admin site, went to Advanced - Firewall Settings and changed 
Enable SPI => Unchecked
UDP Endpoint Filtering => Endpoint Independent
TCP Endpoint Filtering => Endpoint Independent

The problem hasn't happened since...

UPDATE:
I have since changed the firmware of the router to use [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-632). I finally have an awesome router with 8 LAN ports that works as expected! Love dd-wrt.

Comment: i went over your settings and i still have lync problems, is there something i'm missing? http://superuser.com/questions/831385/lync-keeps-dropping-because-of-d-link-dir-601-router-how-to-configure-firewall