# Lync keeps dropping because of D-Link DIR-601 router. How to configure firewall to fix this?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, lync

I saw this article, and it's exactly my problem, but my settings are a bit different and nothing seems to have fixed it so far.

[Why does my D-Link Router keeps dropping my Outlook and Lync connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/321424/why-does-my-d-link-router-keeps-dropping-my-outlook-and-lync-connection)

My current settings (Firewall settings):

1. Enable SPI (checked)
2. UDP endpoint filtering: endpoint independent (other choices Address Restricted & Port And Address Restricted)
3. TCP endpoint filtering: endpoint independent (other choices Address Restricted & Port And Address Restricted)
4. Enable anti-spoof checking (unchecked)
5. APPLICATION LEVEL GATEWAY (ALG) CONFIGURATION: PPTP, IPSec (VPN), RTSP, and SIP (all checked)

Do I just need to get a new router? Or can I configure this to work with Lync messenger so it doesn't keep disconnecting and reconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

just for people who happen to run into this, the only way I could get sync to work was via dd-wrt. I flashed my router and now it's on this firmware and, so far, no issues. was about to buy a new router, but now i don't have to. Win!

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-601